# C# .NET 6 Serilog, How to log requests/responses using UseSerilogRequestLogging without sensitive data

Tags: c#, api, security, .net-6.0, serilog

I'm working on a .NET 6 API and I'm trying to log all user actions with Serilog.

I want to do it without having to add `_logger.Info(...);` in every endpoints for user requests and responses.

After looking on internet, I saw that it is possible to do this without having to develop a custom middleware, using `UseSerilogRequestLogging()`. It works great, but the problem is with sensitive data. Some data like emails, passwords etc. should not be inside the logs for security reasons.

So the question is : How to log all user requests and responses while hiding sensitive data for security reasons ?

Some code from this API :

Get data inside logs :

```cs
app.UseHttpLogging()
    .UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept);
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.ContentType);
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition);
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.ContentEncoding);
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.ContentLength);

    logging.MediaTypeOptions.AddText("application/json");
    logging.MediaTypeOptions.AddText("multipart/form-data");

    logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 4096;
    logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 4096;
});
```

Log configuration and attempt to hide sensitive data :

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.With<UserEnricher>()
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<AddUserDto>(_ => new AddUserDto()
    {
        UserName = _.UserName, UserDescription = _.UserDescription, Password = "****", Email = "****"
    })
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<UserLoginDto>(_ => new UserLoginDto()
    {
        UserName = _.UserName,
        Password = "****"
    })
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<JsonWebToken>(_ => new JsonWebToken("****")));
```

Endpoints with sensitive data :

```cs
[HttpPost("SignUp")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(AddUserDto user)
{
    return Ok(await _userService.AddUser(user));
}

[HttpPost("SignIn")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(UserLoginDto userLogin)
{
    if (await _userService.SignIn(userLogin))
        return Ok((await _jwtService.GenerateJwt((await _userService.GetUser(userLogin.UserName)).Id)).Token);
    return BadRequest(new BlogErrorResponse(nameof(InvalidRequestException),"Bad username or password."));
}
```